# Как работает CSRF-token?

Tags: csrf

Возможно глупый вопрос, но не догоняю. Если cstf-токен хранится в hidden поле формы, то что мешает сайту злоумышленника скачать html-страницу, отпарсить токен, и уже использовать его в ссылке/атаке?

Comment: А он у каждой сессии свой. Чужой токен вы настолько просто не получите.

Comment: @VladD Почему? Ну, например, я авторизировался на сайте. На странице site.com/profile/delete есть форма и кнопка удаления страницы.
Я открыл новую вкладку с вредоносным сайтом. Вредоносный сайт делает file_get_contents страницы site.com/profile/delete получает от туда токен (мы ведь авторизировались) и делает post запрос на удаление.

Comment: Допустим, вы залогинились на сайте X. И я тоже залогинился. И зашли на зловредный сайт Y. Теперь сайт Y посылает запрос на сайт X. Откуда сайт X узнает, что имеется в виду атака на ваш акк, и отдаст ему ваш токен, а не мой? Ответ: никак, он спросит логин и пароль.

Comment: @VladD минутку. Если Y получит html код страницы X разве он не получит token того пользователя кто авторизован. То есть Y открытый на вашем компьютере получит ваш токен. На моём - мой?

Comment: @GroZa открыли хотя бы wiki и почитали бы про CSRF и не было бы таких вопросов - https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0 CSRF-token защищает от подделки запросов третьим лицом. Т.е. что бы например Я не отправил запрос от вашего имени. А в вашем примере вы получите свой токен и сделаете запрос от своего имени.

Comment: @GroZa: А он не получит _тот же_ код, токены должны быть разными.